# Safari v5.1.2 crashes frequently

Tags: macos, safari, adobe-flash, font

I've noticed an enormous number of Safari crashes since switching to Mac OS X Lion, especially the new "reload all windows" crashes that leave Safari slow and unstable.  Any tips for handling those more gracefully?

There are admittedly many crashes attributable directly to Flash.  I'm happily minimizing my Flash exposure using ClickToFlash.  Any other suggestions?  Anyone seen a plugin that relaunches pages in another browser?

There are crashes that I cannot attribute to Flash, like [this page](http://www.metafilter.com/83025/He-Comes).  Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Lion but with chrome.

If i have 10 tabs or pages open and press cmd + Q to quit chrome, when i open the app back up all my tabs are still there.

Plus according to the new press release, chrome is supposed to be the fastest and most secure browser.

Comment: I'll try out Chrome, thanks.  I'd rather learn about debugging Safari's crash to identify the guilty JavaScript or whatever, but alright.